# Why are commas not separated when I mess up in json?

Tags: python, json, parsing

I'm trying to parse site, here is my code, but why, when I import into json, commas are not added

```
with open("all_categories_dict.json") as file:
  all_products = json.load(file)


specifications_list = []
specifications_dict = {}
for product_name, product_href in all_products.items(): 
  url = product_href
  response = requests.get(url)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")

  price = soup.find("div", class_="new_price")
  price = price.text
  describe = soup.find("div", class_="additional_info").find(class_="tabs").find_all("li") 
  for specification in describe:
    specifications_list.append(["Наименование товара", product_name])
    specifications_list.append(["Ссылка", product_href])
    specifications_list.append(["Цена", price])
    specifications_list.append(specification.text.replace('\r\n\t', "").strip().split(':'))
  for i in range(0, len(specifications_list)):
    specifications_dict[specifications_list[i][0]] = specifications_list[i][-1]
  with open("specifications.json", "a") as f:
    json.dump(specifications_dict, f, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Here is screenshot from json

[image]

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

You are dumping several jsons into the same file. You probably want to generate 1 big json

Comment: How am I supposed to do this?

Comment: Instead of using json.dump in the `for`, create a list of your dicts, and then json.dump them outside the loop.

Comment: Can you give any hint? I tried different ways but nothing worked

Comment: ```
result_list = []

for product_name, product_href in all_products.items(): 

....

    result_list.append(specifications_dict)

json.dump(result_list, f, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
```